# RailsアプリをHerokuにデプロイする時に発生するエラーについて

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, centos, heroku

現在開発しているRailsアプリをHerokuにデプロイする時に

```
$ git push heroku master
```

とすると、以下のエラーが発生します。

```
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote:  !
remote:  !     An error occurred while installing ruby-2.1.0-p0
remote:  !
remote:  !     Heroku recommends you use the latest supported Ruby version listed here:（URL)
remote:  !     
remote:  !
remote:  !     For more information on syntax for declaring a Ruby version see:
remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions
remote:  !
remote:  !     Note: Only the most recent version of Ruby 2.1 is supported on Cedar-14
remote:  !
remote:  !     Debug InformationCommand: 'set -o pipefail; curl -L --fail --retry 5 --retry-delay 1 --connect-timeout 3 --max-time 30 https://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/heroku-buildpack-ruby/cedar-14/ruby-2.1.0-p0.tgz -s -o - | tar zxf - ' failed unexpectedly:
remote:  !
remote:  !     gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
remote:  !     tar: Child returned status 1
remote:  !     tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
```

これは単にRubyのバージョンが古いから発生したエラーなのか、それともtarファイルが破損しているから発生したエラーなのか、またどちらともなのかわかりません。

なぜエラーが発生しているのか、またどうすればデプロイを成功させることが出来るのか、教えていただきたいです。よろしくお願いいたします。

開発環境は以下の通りです。
host: macOS
guest: CentOS6.5(Vagrantで管理しています)
Ruby: 2.1.0
Rails: 4.1.0

Answer (score 1):

ご自身でも書かれているようにRubyのバージョンが古いのが原因ですね。

> > Only the most recent version of Ruby 2.1 is supported

とありますので、`2.1`系列を使うのであれば最新の`2.1.10`を使ってください。

特に理由がないのであれば最新の安定版のバージョンを使うのをオススメします。

Comment: とてもわかり易い回答ありがとうございます。
開発環境でのRubyのバージョンを2.1.10にアップデートした上でHerokuにプッシュしたのですが、それでも先述のとおりエラーが出ました。追加の質問で申し訳ありませんが、このような場合の対処方法を教えていただけないでしょうか

Comment: エラーメッセージは完全に同一ですか？ `An error occurred while installing ruby-2.1.0-p0`の部分のバージョンも変わっていないのであればRubyのバージョンを変えれていないので、プロジェクトディレクトリ直下にある`Gemfile`や`.ruby-version`を調べてみてください。

Comment: Gemfileと.ruby-versionのバージョンは修正しましたが、gemが2.1.0のフォルダに入ったままで、Railsコマンド等々が使用できなくなってしまっています。このような場合、どのように対処すればいいでしょうか。どうにかググって見ようと思いましたが、なかなか同じ状況の対処方法が見つかりません。

Comment: `bundle install`してください。